# How can I ensure unique rows in ORMLite database, Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

My simple app parses a site with Jsoup, sends data to OrmLite database, and then shows this data in a ListView. The table in OrmLite database has a simple structure: an autogenerated int primary key _id, and a few String fields (itemId, itemText, itemDate, itemRating).

I add items one by one (this is for educational purposes). If I click the 'add' button very often, I get duplicate entries. Is there a way to guarantee that only unique items (with unique String itemId) will be stored in the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Behind the scene it's a SQLite database so you should be able to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to your column.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/unique), you can add the `UNIQUE` constraint like this:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "itemId", unique = true)
private String itemId;
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. No more duplicates. Though I get an exception now, I'll try to figure out what to do with it.

........... Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column quoteId is not unique (code 19)